# R: Is there a way to overwrite data in an installed R package?

Tags: r, package, overwrite

I've built an R package (SemNetDictionaries) that has several data containing different dictionary glossaries. I would like to provide the user an option to overwrite these dictionaries as they use them with responses that are not included in the base dictionary of the package. Is it possible to allow the user to directly append data in an R package?

1. Users can already create their own separate dictionaries (which can be saved to their computer)
2. I have figured out how to use tools:::makeLazyLoadDB; however, this brings up several warnings when building the package for CRAN (as this is an internal function) as well as corrupts the package.

```
# Load R package
library(SemNetDictionaries)

# Loads the "animals" dictionary in package
base <- SemNetDictionaries::load.dictionaries("animals")

# Word to add to dictionary in package
word2add <- "bluebird"

# Get data file names in package
data.files <- data(package="SemNetDictionaries")$results[,"Item"]

# Load data in package
lazyLoad(paste(system.file("data",package="SemNetDictionaries"),"Rdata",sep="/"))

# Update dictionary
.GlobalEnv[["animals.dictionary"]] <- unique(sort(c(base, word2add)))

# Remove all objects in the environment except for updated dictionary
rm(list = setdiff(ls(),data.files))

# Save data to package
tools:::makeLazyLoadDB(.GlobalEnv, paste(system.file("data",package="SemNetDictionaries"),"Rdata",sep="/"))

# Load dictionaries again (words are updated)
SemNetDictionaries::load.dictionaries("animals")

# This, however, corrupts the R package (see error below)
```

```
Error in get(data(list = dict.long, envir = environment())) : 
  lazy-load database 'C:\Users\apchrist\Documents\R\win-library\3.6\SemNetDictionaries/data/Rdata.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning message:
In get(data(list = dict.long, envir = environment())) :
  internal error -3 in R_decompress1
```

Comment: Check out `usethis::use_data` to build the lazyload db automatically. This is only helpful for you as the package developer though, so not an answer to your question.

Comment: You shouldn't have people modifying data that is shipped and installed with your package. You're better off giving your users tools to keep their own modified copies and use those _instead_ of the version you have in your package.

Comment: Thanks, antoine-sac. This is a nifty function that I did not know about but will use in the future for quickly creating data in my packages.

Thanks, @joran. I have included those tools, so I'll leave it at that.